# Create a database with mysqladmin

Tags: mysql, bash, mysqladmin

I have to create a database from a bash script ,it works but I want to know if I can introduce the user password on the script

```
   #!/bin/bash
    pass ='root'
    mysql -u root -p$pass -e "create database wordpress"
```

but i get

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that but you may not want to.  The entire command line is visible via `ps` (for at least some time, perhaps for the entire duration of the command) and so the password would be exposed that way.  Make sure you're OK with the security implications of that if you do it.

Assuming you do want to make sure you have no space between `-p` and your password, and when assigning the password to a variable in bash make sure there are no spaces around the `=`

Comment: I have tried but I have to introduce the password anyway and security is not important  it's only a practice

Comment: When you have to enter the password anyway, is it for `sudo` or `mysqladmin`?

Comment: No. The password is not shown. It will be replaced by multiple "x".

Comment: @AFS make sure there is no space between `-p` and your password.  Cyrus: the following is from MySQL's documentation on it: This is convenient but insecure. On some systems, your password becomes visible to system status programs such as ps that may be invoked by other users to display command lines. MySQL clients typically overwrite the command-line password argument with zeros during their initialization sequence. However, there is still a brief interval during which the value is visible. Also, on some systems this overwriting strategy is ineffective and the password remains visible to ps.

Comment: Thank you for this important hint!

Comment: Now I trying with myql command ,I have edited the original post

Comment: Now you have a space between `pass` and `=` in the code you posted

Comment: Ok, I'll update my answer to reflect the changes here.